# Can a Rust macro set a variable and return a value at the same time?

Tags: rust

I want to create a macro which will take as parameters `($var:ident, $val:expr)`. The macro should set the variable `$var` to the value of `$val`, clone it, and then return the clone. This is my attempt:

```
macro_rules! my_macro {
    ($var:ident, $val:expr) => {{
        let $var = $val;
        $var.clone()
    }}
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", my_macro!(x, 5));
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

It doesn't work because the `let` statement is inside a block. If I try to solve the problem by changing `{{` to `{`, then it produces a syntax error. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

Macros aren't magic, they just expand to a single expression/statement/item you could otherwise write yourself.  There is no way to write a variable declaration that "escapes" the scope it's defined in.

Answer (score 1):

here is one way you can do this...

```
    #[macro_export]
    macro_rules! create_var {
        ($name:ident, $val:expr) => {
            let $name = $val;
        }
    }

    fn main() {
        create_var!(test, 42);
        println!("{}",test);
    }
```

Output:

```
    42
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because Rust has [hygienic macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygienic_macro), as documented [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.2.0/book/macros.html#hygiene).

Macro hygiene [cannot be disabled currently](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/2054), but it *may* become possible in [Macros 2.0](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/39412):

> [ ] Implement "hygiene bending" for when users want a name from macro def to "escape".

Comment: I don't think this particular problem is related to hygienic macros; the name is supplied by the caller, and is supposed to be used by the caller again.

Comment: @Stefan I think you may be right... can you elaborate on your reasoning?